# Finding a basis for Ker(T) and basis for im(T)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question reads as follows. Define a linear transformation T: $R^5 \rightarrow R^4$ by the rule $T(\vec{v}) = A\vec{v}$ for every $\vec{v} \in R^5$, where A is given by
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 4 \\ 2 & 4&6&4&2\\1&2&3&4&5&\\1&2&3&2&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Find a basis for ker(T) and a basis for im(T)

I know how to find the a basis for ker(A) and a basis for im(A) but what does it mean to find a basis of a linear transformation?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. We aren’t finding a basis for the transformation: a transformation is a map of sets. We want a basis for the actual, underlying subspaces you mention. The kernel happens to be a subspace of the domain of T, while the image is a subspace of the codomain. Both of these facts are easy to check. We can represent a transformation by a matrix (A in this case), and matrix multiplication will represent composition of transformations (i.e., these operations are fully consistent).

Comment: @Brad G. In that case, would it be the same as just calculating the ker(A) and im(A)?

Comment: A represents the transformation T, but it isn’t really correct to say that A possesses either an image or a kernel, which we associate with functions. Matrices represent, but are not themselves, linear functions. With that said, you can use A to find a basis for the image and kernel of T.

Comment: If I were to be super-pedantic, I’d say that what you know how to do is find bases for the _null space_ and _column space_ of $A$. If you interpret $A$, which is just an array of numbers, after all, as representing some linear transformation T, it then makes sense to identify those spaces with the image and kernel of $T$.

Comment: @BradG. That makes sense. Thank you!